# Angular $resource param is not used

Tags: angularjs

So I have this resource:

```
$resource '/media/:medium_id/comments/:comment_id.json', { medium_id: '@medium_id', comment_id: '@comment_id' }
```

And I call this method on it:

```
comment = CommentService.save({ medium_id: $routeParams.medium_id })
```

Now when I do it and look at the console I get this error:

```
POST http://localhost:3000/media/comments.json 404 (Not Found)
```

As you can see the `medium_id` I provided was not inserted into the request `URL`.

What could cause this? If I read the documentation for `$resource` then it seems to me that everything is correct. Yet it does not work..

Comment: It means that `$routeParams.medium_id` is `undefined`. Check `console.log($routeParams.medium_id)`;

Comment: That seems to fix it... The $routeParam I had to reference was just id. If you make an answer about it then I could accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your configuration of the service/resource seems correct. The only reason why resulting request URL can become

```
POST http://localhost:3000/media/comments.json 404 (Not Found)
```

is if `$routeParams.medium_id` is `undefined` value. In this case Angular will skip this placeholder altogether.